# Changing Hyperlink Defaults in Word:Mac 2011

Tags: macos, microsoft-word, hyperlink

I am creating an electronic document in Word that contains hyperlinks to several other Word and pdf docs.  I am using Web layout for my Word docs.  When I reopen them directly, they open in Web layout.  However, once I hyperlink them and open them through the link, they open in Print Layout.  It seems to be a default.  Does anyone know how to change this to have the linked files open in Web layout?

Thank you!